# why don't change page if change return value type

Tags: dart, flutter

it works, can show the `addTask` page

```
var task = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/addTask');
```

don't work, does not change the page.

```
String task = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/addTask');
```

more code:

```
class TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {  

  //....

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Todo List')),
      body: _taskList.isEmpty ? emptyView("No task") : _buildTodoList(),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _pushAddTodoScreen,
        tooltip: 'Add task',
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _pushAddTodoScreen() async {
    var task = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/addTask');
    _addTask(task);
  }

  void _addTask(String taskTitle) async {
    AppDatabase appDatabase = AppDatabase.get();
    await appDatabase.insertTask(taskTitle);
    _updateTasks();
  }
}
```

and how to see the log in the android studio, my app is running on a ios simulator

Comment: Could you put the method you use for that line of code?

Answer (score 1):

Try with explicit types:

```
String task = await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed<String>('/addTask');
```